# Is there a way to exclude an axis from the solidify effect?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, displacement, 3d-printing

Lets say I have this object:
[image]
and I want to solidify it to 3d print it.

I would like to have a constant thickness on the XY plane.
I mean: I want that every 3d printed level has the same thickness.
If I use a Solidify modifier wiht a certain thickness (let's say 2.5mm) It works with the normal of every face, so it works also on z axis and the thickness is not always 2.5mm if measured on XY plane:
[image]

If I go to edit mode and extrude the faces I can't find a way to get what I want.

Is there a way to do it?
I don't need it to be with Solidify. It can be done with Displacement, Animation Nodes, Python or anything else. I just need to do it in a smart and quite fast way.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: If I'm understanding your question right, then this option doesn't exist because excluding a specific axis could result in a non-manifold mesh or overlapping geometry.

Comment: That can be extruding along X/Y only? Or some meshes are too complex?

Comment: The problem is to keep the same identical (and I want a specific value) thickness on all the mesh.

Comment: so extrude first, but don't move, then push/pull the distance you want (with no z)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two steps:

- Extrude, but don't move <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>RMB</kbd>
- Then push/pull using <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to avoid z displacements

"Push/pull" is available in the tool bar (alternate from shrink/flatten) or via menu "mesh/transform/push pull".

Though, you'll have to tune the distance with the mouse as the operator panel does not allow to choose the concerned axis.

[image]

Comment: It isn't what I need. I need a constant thickness along all the object and I want control on that number (the thickness).

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all.  Perhaps it's a Blender 3 thing.  If I hit E and then RMB, nothing has happened.  RMB cancels the extrude.  No additional set of linked faces has been created and I can use push/pull on.